# Two differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove or disprove the following statement: Let $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $g'\neq 0$, then there exists $c\in (a,b)$ s.t.

$$\frac{f(a)-f(c)}{g(c)-g(b)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}.$$

I think this statement is true, it looks very similar to Cauchy's mean value theorem and I believe it might be used in the proof. But I cannot go further at this point. Any idea?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $h(x)$ as follows:
$$
h(x)=(f(a)-f(x))(g(x)-g(b))
$$
clearly $h(a)=h(b)=0$ and therefore there is $c\in(a,b)$ such that $h'(c)=0$, hence:
$$
h'(c)=(f(a)-f(c))g'(c)-f'(c)(g(c)-g(b))\implies \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}=\frac{f(a)-f(c)}{g(c)-g(b)}
$$